# How to concisely write a policy to control access to Amazon EC2 resources based on tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an IAM group called "devops" to which I want to apply a policy that will grant members of that group full access to EC2 instances tagged "Class=devops", and no access to any other EC2 instances. I found this great knowledge center article by Amazon which put me on the right path: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/.

The problem as I see it stems from the "Note" about halfway down that page:

> "Full control" extends to all actions within the EC2 namespace with the exception of those Amazon EC2 API actions that currently do not support resource-level permissions. For more information, see [Unsupported Resource-Level Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permission) in the Amazon EC2 API Reference.

If you follow the link in the note to the [list of unsupported resource-level permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions), you'll find that it's dozens of items long. You'll also find this statement:

> All Amazon EC2 actions can be used in an IAM policy to either grant or deny users permission to use that action. However, not all Amazon EC2 actions support resource-level permissions, which enable you to specify the resources on which an action can be performed. The following Amazon EC2 API actions currently do not support resource-level permissions; therefore, to use these actions in an IAM policy, you must grant users permission to use all resources for the action by using a * wildcard for the Resource element in your statement.
>   In order to grant "allow" permissions to all of these.

If I wanted to grant permissions in this policy to all of those actions which don't support resource-level permissions, my policy would be *hundreds* of lines long! Is there a better and more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple shortcut. A lot of the actions start with the same word such as "Describe". You can cover this list with a wildcard. Example, `"Action" : "ec2:Describe*"`.

Just be careful with actions that will then override your other policy sections that DENY actions for specific resources.